# how to copy text of textbox when the data on textbox is a file from asset folder

Tags: android

I am reading a text file (file.txt) from asset folder and showing it on plain textbox,but if i try to copy it ,it just doesn't happens ,
I have enabled textisselectable in xml file

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/filedisplay"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textIsSelectable="true"
    android:text="" />
```

When i put some output(like doing some operation e.g. addition and the output is put on textbox) on the above textbox its selectable and i can copy and share it ,but if i open a file and try to read it ,it doesn't works

Comment: How can you put the content of a file in it not programmatically?

Comment: @greenapps i mean suppose i do addition and put answer to textbox then its selectable  but if read a text file from asset folder and display it on textbox its not selectable why ? ok i will edit the question

Comment: In both cases you programmatically set text to a text view. So why would the texview behave different?

Comment: @greenapps thats why i have asked the question ,if anyone has tried it

Comment: We will not try unless you post two reproducable examples. One where it goes ok and one that goes wrong.

Comment: @greenapps Rephrasing the question ,How to enable copying and sharing of textbox , if the textbox is displaying a text file from asset folder

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using  `android:textIsSelectable="true"` in xml file I found this

https://developer.android.com/training/sharing/shareaction.html

its working :)